# sails js sockets - Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I am new to sailsjs and stuck while trying to implement this example:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/realtime

api/controllers/SayController.js

```
module.exports = {
  hello: function(req, res) {
    // Make sure this is a socket request (not traditional HTTP)
    if (!req.isSocket) {return res.badRequest();}
    // Have the socket which made the request join the "funSockets" room
    sails.sockets.join(req, 'funSockets');
    // Broadcast a "hello" message to all the fun sockets.
    // This message will be sent to all sockets in the "funSockets" room,
    // but will be ignored by any client sockets that are not listening-- i.e. that didn't call `io.socket.on('hello', ...)`
    sails.sockets.broadcast('funSockets', 'hello', req);
    // Respond to the request with an a-ok message
    return res.ok();
  }
}
```

assets/js/myapp.js

```
io.socket.on('hello', function gotHelloMessage (data) {
  console.log('Socket `' + data.id + '` joined the party!');
});
io.socket.get('/say/hello', function gotResponse(body, response) {
  console.log('Server responded with status code ' + response.statusCode + ' and data: ', body);
})
```

Now when I run application I get error

```
ending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Server.hasOwnProperty (native)
    at _hasBinary (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:45)
    at _hasBinary (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
```

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the parameters for `sails.sockets.broadcast()` have to be tweaked a little. Perhaps the documentation example is outdated or just incomplete. Try this:

**SayController.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  hello: function(req, res) {
    // Make sure this is a socket request (not traditional HTTP)
    if (!req.isSocket) {return res.badRequest();}

    // Have the socket which made the request join the "funSockets" room
    sails.sockets.join(req, 'funSockets');

    // Broadcast a "hello" message to all the fun sockets.
    // This message will be sent to all sockets in the "funSockets" room,
    // but will be ignored by any client sockets that are not listening-- i.e. that didn't call `io.socket.on('hello', ...)`
    //                                             ▼ this is "data" in io.socket.on('hello', function gotHelloMessage (data)
    sails.sockets.broadcast('funSockets', 'hello', {id: 'my id'}, req);

    // Respond to the request with an a-ok message
    // ▼ The object returned here is "body" in io.socket.get('/say/hello', function gotResponse(body, response)
    return res.ok({
        message: "OK"
    });
  }
}
```